# Instagram api not decoding

Tags: python, json, instagram, instagram-api

So I am trying to make a simple instagram downloader. but json giving a hard time

```py
import requests
import os
import json
import shutil

header = {
          "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) "\
                        "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "\
                        "Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"
         }
insta_url = input("enter the url: ")
tail= "?__a=1"
url = insta_url.replace("?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link","") + tail
response = requests.get(url, headers=header).json()
video_location = response["graphql"]["shortcode_media"]["video_url"]
print(video_location)
```

its throwing me an error even though requests is sending a response

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url,headers=header).json()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Check the response code before using `.json()`!

Comment: Isnt response correct??

Comment: That's what the response code will tell you.

Comment: its giving a good response ie, Response [439] for example this is the requests link (https://www.instagram.com/p/CUYEUTBINka/?__a=1)

Comment: All 4xx codes are **bad** response codes.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass login page or (4xx)error ,you most use proxy . i use https://astroproxy.com/